# Building on another machine - Workflow

Tags: build, makefile, workflow

I'm used to building my source in an IDE and having good feedback in the environment. Currently however I'm writing source code in notepad++, ftp'ing it to another machine with specific environment settings, and then building it there and reading the Makefile output to see that it all checks out. After that, I scp the built executable to the actual device to test it.

I'm curious if there are environments that can simplify this. I suppose I could write a script that ftp's changed files and then runs a command through ssh to build them. But I'd like an environment that will parse the makefile output and give me an build report like in most IDE's. I'm not sure how specific this problem is, or if a lot of embedded systems have similar set ups.

Ideally I suppose I would have a machine with the correct build environment, but that isn't the case :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to put the file transfer, remote make invocation and whatever else is necessary into some script (having a one-click build is [important anyway](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html)) and then set that as the build command in my editor. I happen to use [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/), which works fine with the error messages I get from building C++ code via make; personally, I don't find editors not supporting this kind of workflow worth using. There are lots of editors which do.

Oh, and I'd try replacing the ftp with rsync over ssh. It's probably faster, definitely easier to automate, and safer.

Comment: My work machine is running windows.. I guess I'd write my script in batch and then invoke it in the make file, which is set to sublime's build system. Seems simple enough. 

One think I'm unsure of is how to determine if it is necessary to make clean in the batch script, since this makes the make process take much longer.

Comment: Or install cygwin. Has sshd (needs to be set up) and works just fine to put a build system on top of (including calls to devenv.exe to build project files, after copying some environment settings), in my experience.

Comment: You might check out [this sublime SFTP package](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp). It's written by the same person who wrote package control.